# I have change port in xampp but Apache is not working

Tags: apache, xampp

```
[Sat Aug 28 22:29:16.150892 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 13320:tid 584] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Aug 28 22:29:16.211896 2021] [core:warn] [pid 13320:tid 584] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Aug 28 22:29:16.215897 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 13320:tid 584] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.29 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Aug 28 22:29:16.217896 2021] [:emerg] [pid 13320:tid 584] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have used port 1008 for httpd.conf and port 1212 for ssl-httpd.conf.

Comment: Is this an answer, or just additional information about your configuration?